# Magento 2 : shipped items not appearing in email template

Tags: magento2, email-templates, shipment, magento2.4.1

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_shipment_items" shipment_id=$shipment_id order_id=$order_id}}
```

is used to render shipped items in email template but no items appear in email template.

I had also set "`is_legacy`" to `1` in `email_template` table.

Any thoughts, what can be the issue ?

I am using Magento/2.4 (Enterprise)

Comment: I am not sure if issue is faced by other magento user's as well ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? As I have the same issue